# Python - Splitting into letters instead of words

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

What i'm trying to do is grab some text from a folder split it into words, count the words, sort it into a list and write it into a file. All is well except, instead of splitting into words, it splits the text into letters and counts them. Seems like a easy fix but i have no clue what i'm doing so... thanks in advance

```
import os
import os.path
import string

prefix_path = ("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python/sampleTexts")
files = [f for f in os.listdir(prefix_path) if f.endswith(".txt")]
files.sort()
files = [os.path.join(prefix_path,name) for name in files]

textOut = open("texthere.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")

def readText(file):
    for i in file:
        with open(i, "r", encoding= "utf-8") as f:
            textin = f.read()
    first_dict= dict()      
    
    for i in textin:
        i = i.strip()
        i = i.lower()
        i = i.translate(i.maketrans("","", string.punctuation)) 
        words = i.split()

        for word in words:
            if word in first_dict:
                first_dict[word] = first_dict[word] + 1
            else:
                first_dict[word] = 1

    sorted_dict = sorted(first_dict.items(), key= lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    for key, val in sorted_dict:
        print(key," :", val)

    for key, val in sorted_dict:
        textOut.write(key + " :" + str(val) + "\n")
    textOut.close()

readText(files)
```

Comment: `for i in textin:` - `textin` is a string. Iterating through a string goes character by character. Did you mean to do `for i in textin.split()` instead?

Comment: Maybe you meant `textin = f.readlines()`

Comment: Also textin will be the contents of the last file in the list. Perhaps your indentation is not right.

Comment: Are you aware that for i in textin is looping over the characters? Might be easier to just split textin. The default split will work on spaces and newlines.

Comment: oh yeah the answer WAS simple... oh well trial and error amirite? thanks guys, much appreciated

Comment: Why does nobody use a debugger anymore? Because it is easier to let somebody else do it for you!

Comment: I didn't even know that existed until now

Answer (score 0):

f.read() will you give a string of the entire text file such that when you iterate over it `for i in textin` you are iterating over each character. What you probably want is

```
for line in f.readlines():
    for word in line.split():
        blah
```

Comment: split works on f.read. You are making it more complicated than it needs to be.